# Connect to MySQL with TCP

Tags: mysql, tcp, udp

I'm new to TCP world, so i'm trying many things.
How could I connect to a MySQL db with tcp/ip or UDP?
I dont' want to use a library, I want to do it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

TCP. The protocols used are described in [the "Client/Server Protocol"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/PAGE_PROTOCOL.html) and ["X Protocol"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/mysqlx_protocol.html) sections of the source-level documentation.

(The two protocols are an either/or choice. The X Protocol is newer and supports a wider range of features, but may be more difficult to implement than the "classic" client/server protocol.)